# How to make CheckBox bigger on Windows 8

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-8.1

How to make CheckBox bigger on Windows 8 ?

I already know about LayoutTransform, but looks like there is not this property on Windows 8:

```
<CheckBox>
<CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
<ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2" />
</CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
</CheckBox>
```

Comment: If it were me I would just go make the Rectangle's in the [default style template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709910.aspx) larger, but if you just wanted a quick hack like a scaletransform would be, you could just throw it in a `ViewBox` with bigger size on it and set it to stretch to fill.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several ways:

You can increase the overall size by applying a render transform. This will double the height and width during rendering. It may not lay out as you want.

```
<CheckBox RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
    <CheckBox.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"/>
    </CheckBox.RenderTransform>
</CheckBox>
```

You can use a ViewBox, which will lay out in the same spot but won't give full control over the size

```
<Viewbox Height="100">
    <CheckBox>
    </CheckBox>
</Viewbox>
```

Or you can edit the template. This is the most code, but most will be generated for you if you select a checkbox in the designer, right click, and choose "Edit template...". It will provide the most control and you can completely swap out the Checkbox's elements. MSDN's [Quickstart: Control templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465374.aspx) demonstrates changing a Checkbox's template. Depending on the exact look you'll want you'll probably need to increase the sizes of all of the sub-elements (NormalRectangle, CheckGlyph, IndeterminateGlyph, FocusVisualWhite, and FocusVisualBlack).